# Try Except Continue Python not working

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, continue

I have the following try routine:

```
    While true:
    print("back to beginning")  
    self.driver.get("http://mylovelywebsite.com")
        try:
            wait.until(
                EC.title_is("This is my title")
            )
        except TimeoutException as ex:
            print("HERE!")
            print(ex.message)
            self.driver.quit()
            continue
```

It's for selenium, and it just waits to see if the title is there. However, I believe this is just a python problem (the selenium things are working fine)

The problem that happens is that the ex.message is not printing anything out. However, even when I remove this, it doesn't go to the .quit() function and when it reaches the continue statement it just goes back to the print("HERE!") statement (instead of going back to the beginning of the script.

I'm wondering how to make it so that when there is an error, it goes back to the beginning of the script and runs again? Do I have to put the continue and quit() 1 indent less? I'm not sure this would work though, because it would get to the continue statement even if the error wasnt catched.

Comment: 2 questions: have you tried catching general exceptions to see if another problem occurs? And I assume you're inside a for loop?

Comment: I doubt the error is in python correctly executing the exception handling code but instead will be in what is around the few lines you have provided. Can you extend your fragment to see what actually should be `continue`d?

Comment: Hi @languitar yes I have provided some more code. So Im expecting that it will go back to the beginning of the while loop and then print out back to the beginning.

Comment: Hi @YOBA yes in a loop not tried general exceptions, how might i go about this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your indentation is off.
2. `While` should be `while`
3. `true` should be `True`
4. `TimeoutException` has no `message` attribute; Use `str(ex)` instead.
5. You haven't shown if you've imported `TimeoutException`. Use `from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`

### Correct formatting

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

while True:
    print("back to beginning")  
    self.driver.get("http://mylovelywebsite.com")
    try:
        wait.until(EC.title_is("This is my title"))
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        print("HERE!")
        print(str(ex))
        self.driver.quit()
        continue
```

### Sample program that kind of does what you describe

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

timeOut = True 

while True:
    print("back to beginning")  
    try:
        if timeOut: 
            raise TimeoutException("Something caused a timeout")
        else:
            break # leave the while loop because no error occurred
    except TimeoutException as ex:
        print("HERE!")
        print(str(ex))
        continue
```

Infinite loop; terminate with `ctrl+c`.